# What is the real width of the document in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop

Mastering web design and got stuck with the width of the canvas.
If I need to to make a design for a 1920px for PC, what is REAL width of the document to do in Photoshop?
P.s. The site must be full width of the screen for ex as this https://seniorsjournal.org/ in the footer of the site

Comment: my fault, clicked accidentally

Answer (score 0):

Go to 'Image' and 'Canvas size' to set desired dimensions like 1920px if you want to change the format of the canvas.